# Existence of function with zero positive and negative-integer moments

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, moment-problem

I am trying to find the existence of a continuous function defined on $(0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^n f(x)\ dx = \begin{cases} 1, &\mbox{ $n = 0$, }\\ 0, &\mbox { $n \neq 0$, } \end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $n \in \mathbf{Z}$.

If restricted only for $n \ge 0$, Stieltjes gave an example of such a function with zero moments. Let
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \exp\left(-x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)\sin\left(x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)\mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)
\end{align*}
and we can show that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^n f(x)\ dx = 0
\end{align*}
for all $n \ge 0$. I think I can modify this function slightly such that when $n = 0$ the integral is not zero.

However, if we extend $n$ to take negative values, I see no way out. I am not aware of an existing example. Any idea would be appreciated.